# EpiServer - Get content by path

Tags: episerver

Is it possible to get the content item by its path?
I know, that I can do it for pages, but what about other content?

Is it possible to get the item by path e.g. "Root/For All Sites/Catalogs/Mosey/Mens/Jackets" ?

[Epi tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmdzV.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Episerver and you running?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ContentRefere by path:

```
var urlResolver = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<UrlResolver>();
IContent contentData = urlResolver.Route(new UrlBuilder(c.Request.Url.LocalPath));
var contentLinkID = contentData.ContentLink.ID;
```